# Non-integral type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions') is an invalid underlying type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, objective-c++

I am making a calendar on daily view only am just about done and to try and test the app am trying to run it but I keep getting semantic error 1 in red and 3 in yellow.

```
RACSignal+RCLAnimationAdditions.h
Non-integral type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions') is an invalid underlying type
```

The code I have seems to be correct but am I missing something?

…and another issue: a dependency analysis warning.

This is the first error:

```
RACSignal+RCLAnimationAdditions.h
Non-integral type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions') is an invalid underlying type
```

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
    typedef enum : UIViewAnimationOptions {
        RCLAnimationCurveDefault = 0,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseInOut = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseIn = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseOut = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveLinear = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
    } RCLAnimationCurve;
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
    typedef enum : NSUInteger {
        RCLAnimationCurveDefault,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseInOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseIn,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveLinear
    } RCLAnimationCurve;


second code is error says (Assigning to 'id<EKEventEditViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'SettingsViewController *const __strong') (Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/amrhelweh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily-gpcmuomerezkqqfipezqguslloqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Daily.app/Add.png)
(Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/amrhelweh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily-gpcmuomerezkqqfipezqguslloqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Daily.app/Add@2x.png)

    {
    EKEventEditViewController* vc = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
    vc.eventStore = eventStore;

    EKEvent* event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    // Prepopulate all kinds of useful information with you event.
    event.title = @"";
    event.startDate = [NSDate date];
    event.endDate = [NSDate date];
    event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    event.notes = @"";
    event.allDay = NO;
    vc.event = event;

    vc.editViewDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum values must be an integer type. Although the values in `UIViewAnimationOptions` are of type `NSUInteger`, `UIViewAnimationOptions` itself is an enum; thus, this code here is attempting to type the values of `RCLAnimationCurve` as an enum. You'd be better off just using NSUInteger:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
    typedef enum : NSUInteger {
        RCLAnimationCurveDefault = 0,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseInOut = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseIn = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseOut = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveLinear = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
    } RCLAnimationCurve;
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
    typedef enum : NSUInteger {
        RCLAnimationCurveDefault,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseInOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseIn,
        RCLAnimationCurveEaseOut,
        RCLAnimationCurveLinear
    } RCLAnimationCurve;
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but that did not work, i tried it and I cant even close xcode now, i have to force quit it,